# Drop shadow effect in android studio using Kotlin

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, kotlin, shadow

Is there any other way to implement drop shadow effect programmatically using either Kotlin/java in android studio. I know elevation in XML, but it doesn't work the way that I wanted to. I have searched for it, but didn't find any match. Please forgive me, if I miss anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "but it doesn't work the way that I wanted to." Can you explain how you wanted it to work? An image will be good to describe this.

Comment: I mean, more controls, like opacity, direction ..smoothness..etc. I think now we have only control over elevation and TransitionZ. I'm new to android, just curious.. or I miss anything :)